# settimeout not working i dont know why

Tags: javascript

```
                $('form[name=addform]').submit(function() {
                    if(error == true){
                        return false;
                    }else{


                        $('#loading').empty();
                        $('#loading').append("<img src = './images/ajax-loader.gif'/>");
                        $('#loading').show();

                        setTimeout(function(){
                              return true;
                        }, 4000);


                    }
                    error = false;
                });
```

i need to load gif image before executes the return true. i do not use ajax for this please help

Comment: why don't you load the image first and submit the form from js after that? :?

Comment: Is it the form submit using AJAX or not?? If not, it seems will not show the image.

Comment: it is not in AJAX form

Comment: Show() can have a callback function, check the api to figure out how to write the code and you can also set a duration to the show method.

Comment: i need to delay the return statement so that gif image loads before it returns true

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just have the loading image already loaded but hidden with css then show it when it is required? Wouldn't need a false delay waiting for it to be loaded then.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish, but that code won't work. `setTimeout()` does not pause the function it has been called from, nor does the `return` statement in the callback affect it.

Comment: is their any alternative codes that i can use? how can i load a gif image befofe it executes the return statement? pls help.

Comment: So you want to make sure the loader image is shown before submitting the form? I suppose the easiest way would be to have the image pre-loaded in your DOM. Then you only have to set it to visible, which is instantly. You also avoid making your user wait 4 seconds before his request is processed, which I don't think is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is [asynchronous](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh700330.aspx), not synchronous - `setTimeout` will not 'block' the execution of the next line of code. (See related [What is the difference between synchronous and asynchronous programming (in node.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336367/what-is-the-difference-between-synchronous-and-asynchronous-programming-in-node))

To submit the form after a delay (for what purpose is unclear) you will first need to stop the form submitting (by cancelling the event) then submit the form once again as when `setTimeout` callback is executed.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(event) {

  // Prevent the form from submitting
  event.preventDefault();

  // 'this' is referring to the event target
  var form = this;

  // It may not be required to wrap the `form.submit` method but it's usually safer to do so
  setTimeout(function() {
    form.submit()
  }, 4000);

});
```

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/xppNp/1/

Comment: I have added an example for anybody that would like to see my explanation in action.