# Javascript unknown undefined returned

Tags: javascript, node.js

I keep getting `undefined` returned when I run this code:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    filepath = process.argv[2];

function listFilesByExtension(path_to_file, ext) {
    fs.readdir(path_to_file, function (err, files) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(files);
        }
    });
}

console.log(listFilesByExtension(filepath, 'txt'));
```

the `console.log(files)` returns:

```
undefined
[ 'CHANGELOG.md',
  'LICENCE.md',
  'README.md',
  'api.html',
  'dat',
  'data.dat',
  'data.json',
  'learnyounode.dat',
  'learnyounode.sql',
  'learnyounode.txt',
  'md',
  'w00t.dat',
  'w00t.txt',
  'words.dat',
  'wrrrrongdat' ]
```

So the `undefined` is not from there, `console.log(err)` is also return `null`.

Can anybody explain to me why this is happen? thank you

Comment: `listFilesByExtension` doesn't return anything, so your `console.log` for this function call will output `undefined`. This line is the cause: `console.log(listFilesByExtension(filepath, 'txt'));`

Comment: Try to remove the last console.log and just make a call to the function.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: That's an *answer*, not a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your `listFilesByExtension` function does not return anything, so your `console.log` for this function call will output `undefined`.

This line is the cause:

```
console.log(listFilesByExtension(filepath, 'txt'));
```

If you remove the `console.log` form this line, you're unexpected `undefined` will go away.

```
listFilesByExtension(filepath, 'txt');
```

Answer (score 0):

The function listFilesByExtension() does return undefined because there isn't any return statement.
There is also called [asynchronous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336367/what-is-the-difference-between-synchronous-and-asynchronous-programming-in-node) so this code will never return what you want.

You should try synchronous function https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path

eg:

```
function listFilesByExtension(path, ext) {
    var filtered,
        dirContent = fs.readdirSync(path);

    // do your filtering by extension here.
    // The filtered will be an Array of paths filtered out from the dirContent
    return filtered;
}
```

NOTE: there isn't any error handling if the path does not exists

Answer (score -1):

If you write in the browser console: `console.log('Hello, World!');` it will print

Hello, World! 
undefined

That's because `console.log();` returns undefined.

Comment: While all of this is true, they would only see this if they ran this code interactively, in which case they would see `undefined` twice. P.S. Not the downvoter.