# Difference between fs.exists and fs.existsSync

Tags: node.js, fs

While working with the file I/O for node I found these two functions(**fs.exists** and **fs.existsSync**) to check if a file exists in the system. What are the differences between them?

Comment: Careful, those methods are depreciated https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback

Comment: Have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/q/16336367/1531054

Comment: `existsSync` is **not** deprecated, and is fine to use. Only `exists` is deprecated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

exists is non blocking, and you do subsequent work with the file through a callback.

existsSync is blocking and freezes your whole app while it is working.  This can be appealing to new node users because they can continue their code on the next line.  However, once you become used to using callbacks, this is a far inferior way to do things.

Answer (score 1):

One is working in a synchronize way (wait until finished) and another return immediately and return a promise which has a future value.