# specify whether or not a file exists in node.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

i use this code to specify whether or not a file exists:

```
if(fs.exists('../../upload/images/book/2.jpg')){
    console.log("yes the file exist");
} else{
        console.log("there is no file");
      }
```

While the file is there, it always says it does not exist(there is no file)
i use `fs.stat(...)` too , but again it gives the result (there is no file)

Folder structure:

```
root_app  
--------|.tmp  
--------|api  
------------|controllers  
------------------------|BookContoller.js (My code run from here)
--------|...(And the rest of the folders)  
--------|upload  
---------------|images  
----------------------|book  
---------------------------|2.jpg
```

thank you

Comment: Where are you calling this code from, can you show us by way of editing your question to include the app structure and the location of the file with the code relative to the upload folder?

Comment: I'd suggest looking at this `console.log(path.resolve('../../upload/images/book/2.jpg'))` and see exactly what absolute path that is.  Note: you will have to do `const path = require('path')` first to load the `path` module.

Comment: Also depending on which version of node you are using, [`fs.exists()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path) is deprecated

Comment: @ chridam i edit my question  and my node version is 9.4.0 and sails.js is v 0.12.14

Comment: The `..` stuff is going to be relative to the current directory which will depend upon how you start your node.js app.  If you want something to be relative to the module directory, then you should use `__dirname` as the base part of the path.

Comment: @ jfriend00 path.resolve get me: C:\Users\My user name\Desktop\upload\images\book\2.jpg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check synchronously if file/directory exists in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482686/check-synchronously-if-file-directory-exists-in-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

`fs.exists` is asynchronous. To make your code work you could just change it to `fs.existsSync`.

Also you have the wrong path to your file, you need to use `path.resolve` or `__dirname`, so the script will know where to find the file.

```
if(fs.existsSync(path.resolve('../../upload/images/book/2.jpg'))) {
```

See documentation:

- [fs.exists](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback) (deprecated)
- [fs.existsSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path)
- [path.resolve](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths)

Comment: Did not make a difference

Comment: @mascm you also need to use `path.resolve` or `__dirname` to get the full path to the file, see updated answer.

Comment: I have already tested it, but it still says the file does not exist. `path.resolve` get me: `C:\Users\My user name\Desktop\upload\images\book\2.jpg`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969360/difference-between-fs-exists-and-fs-existssync

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved.
Apparently, we should use fs.accessSync() OR fs.access() instead of fs.exists()
[Check out this link](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/1592)

This procedure can also be performed:

```
function Custom_existsSync(filename) {
  try {
    fs.accessSync(filename);
    return true;
  } catch(ex) {
    return false;
  }  

if(Custom_existsSync(filename)){
    ....
}
```

Thanks to everyone who helped me

Comment: `fs.exists` does not return a value. You can only get the result when it is passed to the callback `fs.exists(path, (result) => {});`