# Why does code below fs.readFile callback function run before the callback?

Tags: node.js

```
fs.readFile('input.txt', function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }
  console.log(data.toString());
});

console.log("Program Ended");
```

`input.txt` contains the string `"hello"`.

The above code prints:

```
Program Ended
hello
```

Why does it print `"program ended"` before `"hello"`?
Is it not line by line execution?

Comment: Welcome to the world of asynchronous programming :)

Answer (score 2):

Code inside your callback function (the one which prints the file content) does not block execution. It is executed asynchronously after the file is read.

Comment: Best online resource for NODE?

Comment: You can find more in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336367/what-is-the-difference-between-synchronous-and-asynchronous-programming-in-node

Answer (score 0):

fs.readFile is **asynchronous**, meaning that, as @madox2 said, it will not block execution. If you want to log `Program Ended` after fs.readFile, you can use [fs.readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options). fs.readFileSync is synchronous, meaning that `console.log("Program Ended")` will be executed after.