# d3.js variable not defined, yet in Firefox console, it works

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to read in some csv data, select a specific column(SST), and create an array where each item is: { x: row#, y: SST_for_that_row }.

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var dat=[];
d3.csv("stratus2.txt", function(t) {
dat = t;
});

f=dat.map(function(d,i) { 
return {x:i,y:d.SST} 

</script>
```

My firefox console shows me that the "dat" variable is successfully loaded, but "f" is empty.  However, if I directly type the following into the console, it loads just fine.

```
f=dat.map(function(d,i) { 
return {x:i,y:d.SST}
```

Is there perhaps some sort of scoping issue? Thanks in advance,
Ben

Comment: Calling `d3.csv` is async, meaning you need to do the map/transform inside the callback.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're running into issues keeping your map and return out of your csv callback.  What's going on is your `csv` code hasn't finished (dat isn't set to t), but the callback doesn't block (d3.csv() is asynchronous), so your javascript keeps running, leaving you with an empty map.

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var dat=[];
d3.csv("stratus2.txt", function(t) {
    dat = t;
    f=dat.map(function(d,i) { 
        return {x:i,y:d.SST};
    });
});

</script>
```

Try it this way instead, and check out [Javascript synchronous vs asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336367/what-is-the-difference-between-synchronous-and-asynchronous-programming-in-node) for more information.

The reason this works in your console is because by the time you're entering those lines of code in, your callback has already processed, so `dat` does have an assigned value.