# Is websockets for asynchronis programming only?

Tags: node.js, websocket, autobahn

I am new to asynchronis programming and think I understand the concept:
[What is the difference between synchronous and asynchronous programming (in node.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336367/what-is-the-difference-between-synchronous-and-asynchronous-programming-in-node)

I am looking at a project that uses a websockets data feed:
http://pastebin.com/dMX7mZE0

```
var autobahn = require('autobahn');
var wsuri = "wss://api.poloniex.com";
var connection = new autobahn.Connection({
  url: wsuri,
  realm: "realm1"
});

connection.onopen = function (session) {
        function marketEvent (args,kwargs) {
                console.log(args);
        }
        function tickerEvent (args,kwargs) {
                console.log(args);
        }
        function trollboxEvent (args,kwargs) {
                console.log(args);
        }
        session.subscribe('BTC_XMR', marketEvent);
        session.subscribe('ticker', tickerEvent);
        session.subscribe('trollbox', trollboxEvent);
}

connection.onclose = function () {
  console.log("Websocket connection closed");
}

connection.open();
```

In the example code there are three functions that return data however I am unsure of how to have my code respond to the data returned as these three are continually running simultaneously.

Should I place code to be executed directly within the class methods themselves or would it be better to have the class methods dump their data into a database and then have my code continually reading the database data and acting accordingly?

Thanks and apologies for the noob qn.

Comment: What do you mean by `"how to have my code respond"`?

Comment: I wish to write a bot that trades in response to the data being returned.

Comment: More of a `socket.io` guy myself but the principle remains same as to have your logic function called thru socket events and return the reponse using the socket.

Comment: Thanks Ice however I don't follow (noob). I'll put an example in the original qn.

Comment: Perfect. do that and maybe i can help out more!!

Comment: I think I may have confused myself as I having trouble coming up with an example that demonstrates my concerns. Can I ask what you meant by "return the response using the socket"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117469/discussion-between-iceman-and-user1567212).

Comment: OK, thanks Iceman.