# How to use promises with timeouts in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I have few functions which should be executed one by one in loop and with delay. Here is the code I have:

```
function func1() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    func2().then(); // await in loop until func2() completed       
  }
}

function func2() {
  return new Promise(succes) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      function3().then(); //wait untill function3 and then continue looping
    }
    success();
  }
}

function function3() {
  return new Promise(function(ready) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      // do some stuff
      ready();
    }, 2000);
  });
}
```

But it doesn't work. What I should change?

Comment: Check out sync and async operation difference. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336367/what-is-the-difference-between-synchronous-and-asynchronous-programming-in-node

Comment: Promises are not synchronous

Comment: I thought  that then() is something similar with .net await operator. But it is not

Comment: Also `.then()` is used to attach a callback to a promise.  Using `.then()` on its own with no parameters does nothing but return the same promise again.  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you intended to use is ES8's (ES2017) [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) construct:

```js
async function func1() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    console.log(`func1 waiting for func2 #${i + 1}`);
    await func2(); // await in loop until func2() completed 
    console.log(`Finished iteration ${i} for func1`);
  }
}

async function func2() {
  console.log('Started func2');
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(`func2 waiting for func3 #${i + 1}`);
    await function3(); //wait untill function3 and then continue looping
  }
}

function function3() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
}

func1().then(() => console.log('finished'));
```

For a wider browser support, you can use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2017&code=async%20function%20func1()%20%7B%0A%20%20for%20(var%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%203%3B%20i%2B%2B)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20await%20func2()%3B%20%2F%2F%20await%20in%20loop%20until%20func2()%20completed%20%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aasync%20function%20func2()%20%7B%0A%20%20for%20(var%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%2010%3B%20i%2B%2B)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20await%20function3()%3B%20%2F%2Fwait%20until%20func3%20and%20then%20continue%20looping%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20func3()%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise(resolve%20%3D%3E%20setTimeout(resolve%2C%201000))%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunc1().then(()%20%3D%3E%20console.log('finished'))%3B&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=false)

.

Comment: Yes, this is what I really looking for. How can I be sure tat this code 100% will be executed on user's side? I mean, not all browsers supports EC7.

Comment: You can use [Babel](http://babeljs.io/) to transpile your code to ES5 when deploying

Comment: `async/await` is not part of ES7 (ES2016). It will be part of this year's release, ES2017.

Comment: @FelixKling you're right, I forgot that ES7 was a tiny release of the exponentiation operator and I think one of the `includes` methods. Corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it's a the best solution, but it is some way and i think this easy to implement.

```js
function func1(i){
     i++;
     return new Promise(function(ready){
            setTimeout(function(){  
                func2(i);
                ready(i);           
            }, 1000); 
    });
}

function func2(i = 0){
  if(i < 10){
    func1(i).then((test) => {
      console.log(test);
    })
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
func2();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery's `.each()` , it's synchronous so the next loop won't fire until the previous ends. You can also add callbacks but they are not really needed here.

Comment: `func2().then();` will create a new Promise, then move onto the next loop iteration.  `.each` just uses `for` under the hood.