# node.js get result from mysql query

Tags: mysql, node.js

why I cannot get results?

```
var sql_data = connection.query(sql, function(error, results, fields) {
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
            return;
    }
    var rows = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results[0]));
    console.log(rows);
});
console.log(rows);
```

fiirst console.log is ok, display object,
but second says:

> ReferenceError: rows is not defined

what is wrong?..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336367/what-is-the-difference-between-synchronous-and-asynchronous-programming-in-node

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shouldn't assign asynchronous function to a variable just like you do in first line of your code. You just call it and perform operations on the result with use of `callback` methods (which in this case is `function(error, results, fields)`. Your code should look like below

```
connection.query(sql, function(error, results, fields) {
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
        return;
    }
    var rows = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results[0]));

    // here you can access rows
    console.log(rows);
});

// here it will be undefined
console.log(rows);
```

The `rows` variable in second `console.log` will be undefined because it was defined in different scope. Even if you would do `var rows` above the `connection.query`, it would still be undefined, because you assign it's value inside asynchronous function's callback. You need to read more about this kind of operations.

Comment: but if I want use result after query... is it impossible?

Comment: You can't. You must perform all the operations on the result within the `callback`, so there where your first `console.log(rows)` is.

Answer (score 6):

You should use then ***Promise*** if you want to get the query result. I prefere it to be onest. The Promise runs the command async.

```
function getDomain() {
    return result = await dbQuery('SELECT name FROM virtual_domains ORDER BY id;');
}

// * Important promise function
function dbQuery(databaseQuery) {
    return new Promise(data => {
        db.query(databaseQuery, function (error, result) { // change db->connection for your code
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
                throw error;
            }
            try {
                console.log(result);

                data(result);

            } catch (error) {
                data({});
                throw error;
            }

        });
    });

}
```