# Show a XML file in a HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xmlhttprequest

i want to show my .xml file on my html page in a table. So I wrote a javascript program to get the xml from the webserver and to create a table. But the HTTPRequest Response is always null, because the method onreadystatechange doesn't get called.

My javascript program

```
function LoadXML(dname) {
var xhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
}
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200) {
        return xhttp.responeXML;
    } else {
        return $("#errors").text("XML not found");
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", dname, true);
xhttp.send(false);
}

function UpdateXML() {
xmlDoc = LoadXML('xml/history.xml');
var table = "<tr><th>Auftragsnummer</th><th>Auftraglaufzeit</th><th>Soll-Teile</th><th>Gutteile</th><th>Ausschussteile</th><th>OEE</th></tr>";
if (xmlDoc === null) {
    $("#errors").text("XML document is empty!");
} else {
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Auftrag");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        table += "<tr><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("Auftragsnummer")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("Aufnahmezeit")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("TeileSoll")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("Gutteil")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("Ausschussteile")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("OEE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td></tr>";
    }
}
document.getElementById("history").innerHTML = table;
setTimeout(updateTime, 5000);
}
window.addEventListener("load", UpdateXML);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing async and sync code.

When you make an AJAX request, the code will continue its execution, and `onreadystatechange` will be called eventually. To retrieve the data you have to add a callback to your `LoadXML` function.

First you have to learn about sync and async functions and later read how to implement it to AJAX.

sync/async: [What is the difference between synchronous and asynchronous programming (in node.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336367/what-is-the-difference-between-synchronous-and-asynchronous-programming-in-node) (although it says node, is basically JavaScript)

AJAX examples: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_examples.asp

*Warning*: If you go right to AJAX examples and just copy and paste code without learning the differences between async and sync, you will repeat this problem a lot in JavaScript.

Comment: @Ollifred I'm glad :-) You can upvote/accept this answer then. Also, you must do it with all your questions with answers. Is the main point of this website and if you ratio is too low (0% right now), people will not help you in the future.