# update with upsert: true is not updating in express,mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

```js
var logs = [{
    mobilenumber: '1',
    ref: 3,
    points: 1000,
    ctype: 'mycredit',
    entry: 'sdfsdf',
    entry: 0
}, {
    mobilenumber: '1',
    ref: 6,
    points: 2000,
    ctype: 'mycredit',
    entry: 'sdfsdf',
    entry: 0
}, {
    mobilenumber: '2',
    ref: 7,
    points: 2600,
    ctype: 'mycredit',
    entry: 'sdfsdf',
    entry: 0
}, {
    mobilenumber: '2',
    ref: 15,
    points: -1500,
    ctype: 'mycredit',
    entry: 'sdfsdf',
    entry: 0
}, {
    mobilenumber: '10',
    ref: 15,
    points: 800,
    ctype: 'mycredit',
    entry: 'sdfsdf',
    entry: 0
}, {
    mobilenumber: '11',
    ref: 15,
    points: 110,
    ctype: 'mycredit',
    entry: 'sdfsdf',
    entry: 0
}];

var summary = [];
var positive = 0,
    negative = 0,
    total = 0,
    count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < logs.length; i++) {
    count = 0;
    positive = 0;
    negative = 0;
    total = 0;

    for (var j = i; j < logs.length; j++) {
        if (logs[i].mobilenumber === logs[j].mobilenumber) {
            if (logs[j].points < 0) {
                negative += logs[j].points;
            } else if (logs[j].points >= 0) {
                positive += logs[j].points;
            }

            total += logs[j].points;
            count++;
        }
    }
    i += count - 1;
    var obj = {
        mobilenumber: logs[i].mobilenumber,
        positivepoint: positive,
        negativepoint: negative,
        balancepoints: total
    }
    summary.push(obj);
    
}
```

if you run above code you will get Summary objects

in below code i am trying to insert/update code but insert is working but its not updating

```
var promiseArr = [];
for(var i = 0; i<summary.length;i++) {
    promiseArr.push(saveOrUpdate(summary[i].mobilenumber, summary[i]));
}


function saveOrUpdate (phone, dataToUpdate) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //Update document if found or insert otherwise
    // upsert:true -> If set to true, creates a new document when no document matches the query criteria

        Summary.update({"mobilenumber": phone}, 
            dataToUpdate,
            {upsert: true}, 
            function(err, raw){
                if (err)
                {
                    console.log(err);
                }else
                {
                    console.log(raw);
                }

            });
   });
}
```

Here i am trying to insert or update Summary object in Summary collection .

i am searching mobilenumber in Summarycollection  if mobilenumber already exsist i am updating that document otherwise ,i am creating new document for that mobilenumber

insert is working but if mobilenumber already ther in summary collection its not updating

help me out i m trying since three days

i am using mongoose and database mlab version 3.2.11

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between synchronous and asynchronous programming (in node.js)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336367/what-is-the-difference-between-synchronous-and-asynchronous-programming-in-node)

Comment: Also take a look at async module. https://github.com/caolan/async . It will help.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(obj)` isn't right.

Comment: Don't use `JSON.stringify()`. Pass your object directly i.e. `obj`

Comment: Guys he use sync FOR to run async DB operations.. Which will lead to very big problems in future. So JSON.stringify may work here, but still code need to be re-write in async way, using promises or async module.

Comment: can you help me out @Mykola Borysyuk

Comment: Give me a min..Working on it.

Comment: Post code for Summary class. Where you get it from...and what version of mongo and driver you use.

Comment: i am using mlab mongod version: 3.2.11 (MMAPv1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 var promiseArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < summary.length; i++) {
        promiseArr.push(saveOrUpdate(summary[i].mobilenumber, summary[i]));
    }


    function saveOrUpdate(phone, dataToUpdate) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            //Update document if found or insert otherwise
            // upsert:true -> If set to true, creates a new document when no document matches the query criteria
            Summary.findOne({
                "mobilenumber": phone
            }, function(err, data) {
                var newSummary = dataToUpdate;
                console.log(data);
                console.log(newSummary);
                if (data) {
                    newSummary.negativepoint += data.negativepoint;
                    newSummary.positivepoint += data.positivepoint;
                    newSummary.balancepoints += data.balancepoints;
                }
                Summary.update({
                        "mobilenumber": phone
                    },
                    dataToUpdate, {
                        upsert: true
                    },
                    function(err, raw) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        } else {
                            console.log(raw);
                        }

                    });

            });



        });
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

So first take a look at this. [What is the difference between synchronous and asynchronous programming (in node.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336367/what-is-the-difference-between-synchronous-and-asynchronous-programming-in-node) . Don't ever use sync and async operations in same place without full understanding what's going on.

Let's try to rewrite your code using async approach.
First let's create promise method

```
function saveOrUpdate (phone, dataToUpdate) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //Update document if found or insert otherwise
    // upsert:true -> If set to true, creates a new document when no document matches the query criteria
       Summary.updateOne({"mobilenumber": phone}, 
            {$set : dataToUpdate}, 
            {upsert: true}, 
            function(err){
                  err ? reject(err) : resolve();
            });
   });
}
```

Now just make array of promises

```
var promiseArr = [];
for(var i = 0; i<summary.length;i++) {
    promiseArr.push(saveOrUpdate(summary[i].mobilenumber, summary[i]));
}
```

Run promises using Promise.All and catch results.

```
Promise.all(promiseArr)
.then((res) => console.log("All done"))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Mongo update docs
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/
Mongo updateOne docs https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/

Promises https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

if you using mongoose as a driver. Read docs to see how you can update document by query. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html

Mongo DB native driver allows you to use all new mongo features and methods. http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: getting error Waiting...
TypeError: Summary.updateOne is not a function

Comment: Well. What mongodb driver you using to query DB? What version of mongo?

Comment: I reccomend using this one http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#updateOne

Comment: i am using mlab  mongod version: 3.2.11 (MMAPv1)

Comment: Ok..what library you using to query documents in mongo mLab? to do find or update?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144232/discussion-between-mykola-borysyuk-and-its-me).