# .populate() issue with references

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/DocTest');

var patientsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
//This is the value I wanna populate in the rdvs collection.

ssn: String
//But I can't see to have it working.

});


var patients = mongoose.model('patients', patientsSchema);

var Max = new patients({
ssn: "okokok" 
});
Max.save(function (err) {
if (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
else {
    console.log('wink')
}
});

var rdvsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
Heure: {
    type: Date
},
patient: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'patients'
}
});

var rdvs = mongoose.model('rdvs', rdvsSchema);

var rdvs1 = new rdvs({
Heure: 14
}
);
rdvs1.save(function (err) {
if (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
else {
    console.log('wonk')
}
});
```

This is the request I'm trying to have working :

```
rdvs.findOne().populate('patient').exec(function(err, rdvs){
console.log (rdvs.patient.ssn)
});
```

I'm struggling here, the issue here is I wanna add ssn's value from patients to my rdvs collection.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose operations are [asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336367/what-is-the-difference-between-synchronous-and-asynchronous-programming-in-node). You need to wait for the operation is done before doing other things. In your case, the second query depends on the response of your first query -- therefore you need to nest your operations.

```
// setup schemas
var patientSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    ssn: String
});

var rdvSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    Heure: Number, // changed: you're expecting a number
    patient: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Patient' }
});

var Patient = mongoose.model('Patient', patientSchema);
var Rdv = mongoose.model('Rdv', rdvSchema);

// create a new patient
Patient.create({ ssn: "okokok" }, function (err, patient) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    if (!patient) {
        console.log('patient could not be created');
        return;
    }
    // you can only create a RDV once a patient has been created
    Rdv.create({ Heure: 14, patient: patient._id }, function (err, rdv) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        if (!rdv) {
            console.log('rdv could not be created');
            return;
        }
        // send response
    });
});
```

Aside: get into the habit of naming your variables properly. Usually, [models](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) are singular and capitalized e.g. `Patient` and [documents](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html) are lowercase e.g. `patient`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I still have a question tho.