# Displaying data from a Mongodb collection in ejs using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I am brand new to programming. I have a collection called "Practice" in my local database which has "name, role, org". I am trying to figure out how to print this info in a .ejs file using mongoose.

In my server.js, I have

```
require('./app/routes.js')(app, passport);     
mongoose.connect(configDB.url); // connect to our database
    var schema = mongoose.Schema;
    mongoose.model('practice', new schema({ Name: String, Role: String, Org: String}),'practice');
    var practice = mongoose.model('practice');
    practice.find({}, function(err, data) { console.log(err, data); });
```

In the routes,

```
app.get('/profileface', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
        res.render('profileface.ejs', {
            user : req.user
        });
    });
```

In the views folder, file profileface.ejs, I have the below to print the name from my "practice" collection.

```
<%= practice.name %>
```

Although it is printing in the console, when I try to access profileface.ejs, I get the following error.

```
ReferenceError: C:\Users\SEESCHU\Desktop\Linneus university\Assignments\302\Assignment 2\code\Test3\views\profileface.ejs:36 34| </div> 35| >> 36| <%= practice.name %> 37| 38| <!-- <div class="text-center"> 39| <p>Assignment for 4ME302</p> practice is not defined at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\SEESCHU\Desktop\Linneus university\Assignments\302\Assignment 2\code\Test3\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:237:14), <anonymous>:30:986) at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\SEESCHU\Desktop\Linneus university\Assignments\302\Assignment 2\code\Test3\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:237:14), <anonymous>:30:1154) at C:\Users\SEESCHU\Desktop\Linneus university\Assignments\302\Assignment 2\code\Test3\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:250:15 at Object.exports.render (C:\Users\SEESCHU\Desktop\Linneus university\Assignments\302\Assignment 2\code\Test3\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:288:13) at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\SEESCHU\Desktop\Linneus university\Assignments\302\Assignment 2\code\Test3\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:318:20) at View.render (C:\Users\SEESCHU\Desktop\Linneus university\Assignments\302\Assignment 2\code\Test3\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:76:8) at Function.app.render (C:\Users\SEESCHU\Desktop\Linneus university\Assignments\302\Assignment 2\code\Test3\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:504:10) at ServerResponse.res.render (C:\Users\SEESCHU\Desktop\Linneus university\Assignments\302\Assignment 2\code\Test3\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:798:7) at C:\Users\SEESCHU\Desktop\Linneus university\Assignments\302\Assignment 2\code\Test3\app\routes.js:30:7 at callbacks (C:\Users\SEESCHU\Desktop\Linneus university\Assignments\302\Assignment 2\code\Test3\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:164:37) at isLoggedIn (C:\Users\SEESCHU\Desktop\Linneus university\Assignments\302\Assignment 2\code\Test3\app\routes.js:116:10) at callbacks (C:\Users\SEESCHU\Desktop\Linneus university\Assignments\302\Assignment 2\code\Test3\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:164:37) at param (C:\Users\SEESCHU\Desktop\Linneus university\Assignments\302\Assignment 2\code\Test3\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:138:11) at pass (C:\Users\SEESCHU\Desktop\Linneus university\Assignments\302\Assignment 2\code\Test3\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:145:5) at Router._dispatch (C:\Users\SEESCHU\Desktop\Linneus university\Assignments\302\Assignment 2\code\Test3\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:173:5) at Object.router (C:\Users\SEESCHU\Desktop\Linneus university\Assignments\302\Assignment 2\code\Test3\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:33:10)
```

I have spent the last 2 days trying to figure it out by googling but now I give up. I would really appreciate if you can help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Extra** In programming, you want to keep your code organized.

Create a file e.g. *PracticeModel.js* inside *app* folder and move your schema logic there

```
var PracticeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
    Name: String, 
    Role: String, 
    Org: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('practice', PracticeSchema, 'practice');
```

In your *routes.js*, include the newly created file at the top

```
var PracticeModel = require('./PracticeModel.js');
```

**Your problem** You need to (1) move the query inside your route handler and (2) pass the resultset `data` to the view

```
app.get('/profileface', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    // mongoose operations are asynchronous, so you need to wait 
    PracticeModel.find({}, function(err, data) {
        // note that data is an array of objects, not a single object!
        res.render('profileface.ejs', {
            user : req.user,
            practices: data
        });
    });
});
```

In your view *profileface.ejs*, you need to iterate over the passed **practices** array

```
<% practices.forEach(function (practice) { %>
    <%= practice.Name %> <!-- note you defined the field as Name not name -->
<% }) %>
```

Your *server.js* would look like this after the changes

```
mongoose.connect(configDB.url);
require('./app/routes.js')(app, passport);
```

Read this post on [synchronous vs asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336367/what-is-the-difference-between-synchronous-and-asynchronous-programming-in-node). Most of the things you do in Node.js is usually asynchronous.

Comment: I don't know how to thank you. This is my third night in a row trying to figure it out. IT WORKED.

Comment: Really thanks man, your explanation is so useful. Have a great and happy new year!

Answer (score 0):

**Hi I had the same problem, So I Did This and it worked**

```
collection(users).find({}, (err, found) => {
 if(err){
 console.log(err)
 }else{
 res.render("Dashboard", {DataFound: found})
 }
})
```