# wait findOneAndUpdate in a loop end

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
names.forEach((o, i) => {
                Name.findOneAndUpdate({name: o.name}, o, {upsert: true, 'new': true})
                .then(result => {
                    res.json(result);
                })
            })
```

I cant do res.json in above's loop, how to do handle this case? I want to find name exist or not, if exist don't do anything, otherwise insert the names.

Comment: You can use [async.map()](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map) 
 but ensure you execute `findOneAndUpdate` using a callback instead of returning a Promise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all read this.

[What is the difference between synchronous and asynchronous programming (in node.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336367/what-is-the-difference-between-synchronous-and-asynchronous-programming-in-node)

You mixing it up.

To fix your code you can use promises...

For example

```
function runUpdate(obj) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     //you update code here

    Name.findOneAndUpdate({name: obj.name}, {$setOnInsert: obj}, { upsert: true })
      .then(result => resolve())
      .catch(err => reject(err))
    });
  });
}
```

Now you can run loop and use promise all

```
let promiseArr = [];
names.forEach(obj => promiseArr.push(runUpdate(obj)));
```

Finally

```
Promise.all(promiseArr)
.then((res) => //res.json here)
.catch(err => //err res here)
```

About not updating documents on existanse. Check this out.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/#op._S_setOnInsert

Hope this helps.

Comment: upsert true is needed because if the name is not exist, create a new name.

Comment: Oh sorry my mistake..Give me a second

Comment: yes, if exist don't insert. It's like you do scraping for a list and then put into db, you don't want to even update it if it exist, if it don't insert a new document.

Comment: I tried your code, `setOnInsert` is needed? I simply state `obj` and it just worked.

Comment: Well. I think so. Because with upsert true if document were found it will run $set if not it will run insert with $set and $setOnInsert from docs. So to make sure that you only do stuff on isert you need this operator.

Comment: No problem. Glad it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
const promises = names.map(async obj => 
   await Name.findOneAndUpdate(
      {name: obj.name}, 
      obj, 
      {upsert: true, 'new': true}
   )
)
await Promise.all(promises)

console.log('test')
```

if you run this code you will see 'test' only appears after the promises.