# Why doesn't Gulp see the folder?

Tags: node.js, gulp

I use Gulp 4 and I have this task:

```
gulp.task('deploy', gulp.series('clean', 'handlers:all', 'deployment'));
```

The task call three other tasks:

1. Task `clean`: removes the build folder.
2. Task `handlers:all`: re-creates the build folder and adds files there.
3. Task `deployment`: transfers the contents of the build folder to another location

I have a problem with task the `deployment` which look something like this:

```
gulp.task('deployment', done => {
    gulp.src('./build/')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('../other-project/'));
});
```

gulp.src() can't find the build folder because it was deleted by the task `clean`. When I set the timeout there are no problems. But this solution is bad.

```
gulp.task('deployment', done => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        gulp.src('./build/')
            .pipe(gulp.dest('../other-project/'));
    }, 2000);
});
```

How do I solve this problem?

Task `clean`:

```
gulp.task('clean', done => {
    del('./build/');
    done();
});
```

Task `handlers:all`:

```
gulp.task('handlers:all', gulp.parallel('scripts', 'templates', 'styles', 'fonts', 'favicons', 'images', 'svg', 'dist'));
```

Comment: can you post the `handlers:all` script as well?

Comment: @AlexScr these are just parallel tasks: `gulp.task('handlers:all', gulp.parallel('scripts', 'templates', 'styles', 'fonts', 'favicons', 'images', 'svg', 'dist'));`

Comment: Post your clean as well.

Comment: @Nick I added this to the question.

Comment: Quick note: hopefully you have return statements or are calling the done() function in all your tasks.  You don't in your original "deployment' task. I assume one or more of the tasks in your 'handlers:all' is recreating the build folder: gulp.dest('./build').  Second, there is no reason to use './build/' just use './build'.

Comment: Agree with @Mark. Seems like `clean & handlers:all`  tasks are async, and `gulp` doesn't  know when to start next task. So you may want to use a callback function `done` once you removed all folders. Plus you should do same things for your `handlers:all` task as well. Just to make sure that it runs like a `sync` but it's actually `async` flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace your `clean` task to the next one:

```
gulp.task('clean', done => {
  del('./build/').then(() => done());
});
```

It needs because of `del` package returns a promise and you should tell gulp to wait till it will be resolved. The other option can be [`del.sync`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/del).

I'm not sure about rest of tasks but it should follow the same process. If you have any async tasks - call `done` in the right place.

It might be useful for you [`async vs sync`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336367/what-is-the-difference-between-synchronous-and-asynchronous-programming-in-node)

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Yes, it works! In the rest tasks I added `.on('end', done)` after `.pipe(gulp.dest(...))`.