# scope or context issue with fs.readdir

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm building a command handler for an application and I'm wanting to build a dictionary from files that have the right modules. The dictionary is being set properly inside of the fs.readdir, but things are happening out of order for me and I can't figure out if its a context or a synchronous problem I'm not seeing.

```
        const dict = new Map();
        fs.readdir(filePath, (err, files) => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            console.log(files);
            let jsfile = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js");
            if (jsfile.length <= 0) {
                console.log("didn't see any commands.");
                return;
            }
                jsfile.forEach((f) => {
                    console.log(f);
                    let props = require(`${filePath}/${f}`);
                    try {
                        if(props.help.name)
                            dict.set(props.help.name, props);
                        console.log(`${f} was loaded.`);
                    }
                    catch (e) {

                    }
                });

            let run = dict.get('kata1');
            run.run();
            console.log(dict);
        });
        console.log(dict + "2");
```

for some reason console.log(dict+ "2"); populating first, then the rest of the logs in fs.readdir run. I've tried putting the read in a function and calling that function first, but I can't seem to access dict outside of the fs.readdir.

Comment: I've marked as duplicate because `fs.readdir` is async and that question provide the answer how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

like you mentioned it's a synchronous problem `fs.readdir` is async function.

the callback `(err, files) =>` will call after all the sync function in the eventloop,

this -> `console.log(dict + "2");` is a sync function.

read this:

- [Is JavaScript synchronous or asynchronous? What the hell is a promise?](https://medium.com/@kvosswinkel/is-javascript-synchronous-or-asynchronous-what-the-hell-is-a-promise-7aa9dd8f3bfb)
- [What is the difference between synchronous and asynchronous programming (in node.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336367/what-is-the-difference-between-synchronous-and-asynchronous-programming-in-node)