# How to export the value of an observable and assign to a variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs, redux-observable

I'm trying to assign a value of an observable to a variable but it returns Undefined.

Is there any way to assign this value to a variable outside the subscribe method?

```
new Observable((observer) => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = () => {
    observer.next(reader.result);
    observer.complete();
  };
  reader.onerror = e => observer.error(e);
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  return () => {
    if (reader.readyState === 1) {
      reader.abort();
    }
  };
});
let result;
getBase64(blob)
 .subscribe((base64) => { result = base64; });
return result;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be running into the [difference between synchronous and asynchronous programming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48663692/4289902).

In a nutshell, `result` is returned immediately, while `observer.next` is only called once the `onload` function is executed *some time in the future* which might be immediately, seconds later, or even never.

So once you try to do something asynchronous, you effectively have to execute the result handler as a different block of code.

If I were wanting to get the result from a FileReader, I'd usually go for a promise approach, (rather than an Observable) as I'm only expecting a single value (or an error).  While similar, Promises are a bit simpler, while Observables are more powerful.

A rough example:

```
function getFileContents(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = evt => resolve(evt.target.result);
    reader.onerror = err => reject(err);
    reader.readAsText(file);
  });
}
```

This function will give you back a `Promise<string>` (a promise that contains a string).  You still need to "unwrap" the promise to get the internal value though (using `then` or `async`/`await`-style programming).

If you are really sure you want an observable, then I'd probably still use the above promise function, but call it like this:

```
import { from } from 'rxjs'; 

function getFileContents(file) {
  ...
}

const myObservable = from(getFileContents(fileBlob));
```

Comment: Thanks Jono, Promises are the better approach. I declared a value `let result = '';` and then used `then` to unwrap the data like this: `getFileContents(blob).then(base64 => result = base64);` but still when I log my `result` variable in console it shows empty string!

Comment: Yes, it will, because `result` is returned by the function before its value is assigned in the `then` handler.  I suggest you add some `console.log` calls in a few places in the function and in the `then` handler to see the order the code runs in.