# Success data returns null from AJAX GET type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using the following codes to get `success data` into a `variable`:

```
    var compdet = null;

    $.ajax({
        url: uri2 + "/" + $("#textbox_id").val(),
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            compdet = data;
        }
    });
```

And to check if my `var compdet` has value in it, I added:

```
    console.log(compdet);
```

Sadly, it returns JUST `null`. So I tried putting the `console.log` into

```
    success: function (data) { console.log(data); }
```

And it returns the output that I want to see. Anyone who can explain this to me?

> I realized something here. You can actually make `Javascript` function `async` and `await AJAX` calls.

For example:

```
async function func_name() {

    await $.ajax({
        // some codes here
    });

}
```

Comment: Where exactly have you placed the `console.log(compdet);`

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt after the `$.ajax({});` lines

Comment: Your ajax will be `asynchronous` in nature. Please refer to the linked dupe for more info on how to proceed.

Comment: you can assign the response of ajax i.e. data after ajax and with in ajax scope. and also console the compdet variable with in ajax code after assiging because javascript is asynchronous when using http request. it is not waiting for any http request response.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript execution is [**synchronous**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Synchronous) but [**AJAX**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) is [**asynchronous**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous). If you have any code after **AJAX** it might execute before completing the AJAX. That's why you are getting the value `null`.

In this scenario you can execute your next code stuff inside `success()` callback or call another method to execute the next code chunk.

An example with method call:

```
function next(compdet) {
    // code stuff
}

$.ajax({
    url: uri2 + "/" + $("#textbox_id").val(),
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        next(data)
    }
});
```

See the difference between [**synchronous vs asynchronous**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336367/what-is-the-difference-between-synchronous-and-asynchronous-programming-in-node).

Comment: You have a typo in the parameter of function call

Comment: Yes, corrected. Thanks.

Comment: @MH2K9, if i'll use `function next(compdet) { console.log }` it outputs correctly. However, if i'll put the `compdet` into a `global variable`, i still get null.

Comment: You are getting null because of the asynchronous nature of AJAX.

Comment: Isnt the `next()` enough?

Comment: if you use next() then no need to use global variable. Perform all your tasks in next() method. If you need it to use global then use `async: flase` in AJAX.