# NodeJS & Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am facing a strange issue while using `NodeJS` and `Socket.io`.

Server which receive data via `ZeroMQ`. That work perfect.
For each message from `ZeroMQ`, I used `sockets.volatile.emit` to send that to all connected clients.
The issue arise only for large number of connected accounts (more than 100), it seems there is a queue on the sending to clients (client receive message in delay that keep increasing)

#### Note : Each connected client received each message from ZeroMQ, so basically for more client there is more data sent over the socket.IO.

Via Logs/Debug i know the receive from `ZeroMQ` has no delay and all works on that part. The emitting seems to have a queue or delay that keeps increasing.

The messages rate is `80` messages/sec for each client.

`Note:` NodeJS 0.10.20 and Socket.IO 0.9.16.

#### How can I control that to prevent client received old messages ?

Comment: If you like you can post some code, and we can find a solution, seems that your not the only one having this problem?

Comment: yeah some code would be helpful, or at the very least describe what happens between when the server receiving the ZeroMQ message and when the server writes to the socket.

Answer (score 13):

Checkout this [**article**](https://www.airpair.com/node.js/posts/top-10-mistakes-node-developers-make) it will tell you a lot of the basic mistakes and it's, about blocking the event loop which seems pretty similar to what your doing.

Maybe use tools such as: [**Debug**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) and [**Blocked**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blocked) i think it would help solve you'r issue. Both to debug where you creating a bottleneck on performance & other basic issues.

Alternatively hook your node project up on **PM2** and bind it to [**Keymetrics.IO**](https://app.keymetrics.io/) this will give you a good view into your server and why it's running slow and why you make a performance bottleneck.

Its hard to solve your problem without code examples but here is 3 reasons why your app or you could create bottlenecks (maybe unknowingly):

- Parsing a big json payload with the JSON.parse function.
- Trying to do syntax highlighting on a big file on the backend (with something like Ace or highlight.js).
- Parsing a big output in one go (such as the output of a git log command from a child process).

More info in the first [**article**](https://www.airpair.com/node.js/posts/top-10-mistakes-node-developers-make) in section 2 called *"Blocking the event loop"*

A question related to yours, **[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28227842/does-socket-io-nodejs-emit-callback-affects-server-perormance-like-does-it-bl)**.

Wanna know more about the Event loop i can warmly direct you to a tread *"[How the single threaded non blocking IO model works in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795145/how-the-single-threaded-non-blocking-io-model-works-in-node-js)"*

Here is a model of the Node.js Processing model, to see what happens on the event loop and its surroundings

[image: Node.js processing model]

Comment: that's one hell of an answer friend

Comment: @TheOnin i felt that as well, but still no accepted question sadly :D

Answer (score 0):

If it turns out that you're not blocking the event loop in any terrible way, then you might be hitting the limits on what **socket.io** can handle for your specific application.  If thats the case then you might consider scaling up your instances.

Check out this article for more information:
http://drewww.github.io/socket.io-benchmarking/