# Safe to implement a long-polling client in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to hook up [Hubot](http://hubot.github.com/) to my bigcorp chat system. There is a REST API, but it relies in its clients long polling.

This is my first node.js project, and I'm told node.js apps are single threaded.  Will long polling block my thread, or is I/O done on another thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is safe.

Node has asynchronous (non-blocking) IO. See [How the single threaded non blocking IO model works in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795145/how-the-single-threaded-non-blocking-io-model-works-in-node-js) for further details