# How are callback functions executed in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I've just started learning node.js and express and there's something that confuses me a bit in the "hello world" example on the express.js website. In the example, they refer to the server variable inside the callback function.

```
var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;

    console.log('App listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Does `app.listen()` return a value to server variable before it executes the callback function? How can it do that and how does it work? Is this the same for all callback functions in node (and javascript)?

I would just like a simple explanation of the execution process.

To be clear, I understand that the callback function has access to the server variable. But if the *app.listen* method executes the callback function before it returns a value to the *server* variable, wouldn't that mean that the *server* variable is still underfined when you try to access *server.adress()*? That is what I don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does app.listen() return a value to server variable before it executes the callback function?

Yes, exactly. `app.listen()` resembles to the [plain Node.js `server.listen` method](https://iojs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback).
The callback is an shortcut for assigning the server an listener to the `listening` event.

You could do the same with the following code:

```
var server = app.listen( 3000 );
server.on( "listening", function () {
  console.log( "server is listening in port 3000" );
});
```

> How can it do that and how does it work? Is this the same for all callback functions in node (and javascript)?

This happens because [IO events in Node.js are all run asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795145/how-the-single-threaded-non-blocking-io-model-works-in-node-js) (with exceptions from the [`fs` module](https://iojs.org/api/fs.html)) - this is, they will only take place when other synchronous code have finished to run.

This works the same in browser JS - if you run some JS process synchronously, any events triggered (like `click`, `blur`, etc) will only execute after that one finishes.

Answer (score 1):

A function has access to all the variables that existed in the scope where it was **created** (unless it masks them).

```
var in_the_global_scope = 1;
function outer() {
    function inner() {
        alert(in_the_global_scope);
    }
    inner();
}
```

`inner` has access to any variable declared in `inner`, `outer` and the global scope.

A function being a callback isn't really relevant.

The `listen` method itself **doesn't** have access to `server` because `listen` was created in a different scope.

> But if it returns a value, how can it then execute the callback function?

Because it doesn't *just* execute the callback. It waits for an event and the callback gets fired in reaction to that.

```js
var timeOutId = setTimeout(function() {
  alert(timeOutId);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I know that the callback function has access to the server variable. But if the server variable isn't yet defined, it doesn't have any methods, right? So app.listen must **return** a value to it before the callback is executed, right? But if it returns a value, how can it then execute the callback function? That is what I don't understand.

Comment: "But if the server variable isn't yet defined, it doesn't have any methods, right?" — It is defined by the time the callback function is called.

Comment: "But if it returns a value, how can it then execute the callback function?" —  Because it sets up an event handler. Updated answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

var server is being assigned to the function app.listen()

If you look at the express documentation it states that

> The app.listen() method is a convenience method for the following (for HTTP only):

```
app.listen = function() {
  var server = http.createServer(this);
  return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};
```

By setting var server = app.listen() and the fact that app.listen() returns something, you're essentially setting var server to whatever app.listen() return.

Answer (score 0):

You can thinking like that, the `app.listen()` return an object `server` which include information of how to run the server, example `port`, `address`, like a paper of instructions. Then it go to run server.

When server was run, the application also add some remark on that instructions example `porcessid`
then server is also call callback function `app.listen(port[, callback])`. Withing that function, we can access server information back from instruction and remarks.