# Doubts about async web api 2 operation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

In some article about asynchronous web api 2 actions, I have found following code that shows how to implement async operations in Web Api 2:

```
 public class UserController : ApiController
        {
            ApiSecurityEntities _db = new ApiSecurityEntities();

            public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Delete(Int32 Id)
            {
                 var record = await _db.UserMaster.Where(f => f.id == Id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
                 if (record != null)
                 {
                     _db.UserMaster.Remove(record);
                     await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                     return Ok();
                 }
                 return NotFound();
            }
        }
```

I suppose that this code is **not** async, but it's only wrapped with `async/await` words. Can you dispel my doubts?

**#EDIT**

Reasons why I'm supposing that isn't truly async code:

- After first `await` there is only `if` statement that must wait for previous operation and no other work will be done after this block, so it will be run synchronously
- After second `await` there is `return` statement, so it must wait until `_db.SaveChangesAsync();` will be done

Comment: Why should it not be async?

Comment: Having the `await` keyword will allow the framework to perform other work while it is waiting for the database to return data..

Comment: "I suppose that this code is not async" - can you clarify *why* you suppose this code is not async? You have two async db operations here

Comment: @TryingToImprove you right, but in this case no other work will be done, so this example doesn't make sense?

Comment: @mkul No. The entire computer can do other things, not just your code.. Also this is a Web API controller, so there can be multiple users/threads..

Comment: I believe you may be confusing async with multithreading.

Comment: ... which you [should not](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17661428/11683).

Comment: I updated question, please refer to my #EDIT section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is absolutely real async in terms of I/O.

> In computer science, asynchronous I/O, or "Non-sequential I/O" is a
>   form of input/output processing that permits other processing to
>   continue before the transmission has finished.

From [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O).

In your case your method does not block any thread while you're waiting for I/O to completes (DB operations), using await you tell the current thread that it can return to the `ThreadPool` and do any other work before the I/O operation completes.

Any thread (some kind of processing unit) will not be blocked while the DB doing his job which follows the asynchrouns definition.

**#EDIT**

As you said your code execution order does not change and it needs the results from the DB to execute the next statements, but(!) although it seems that this code is blocking (aka sync) it [will not block any thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) while the I/O operation executing.
The `await` keyword allows you to "wait" in an async way for the results and when the I/O is done it will continue executing the rest of the method.

Comment: So it's better to put all database operations in `async/await` even if code looks like it will run operations synchronously?

Comment: Exactly, by doing this you can use your resources (threads) in more effective way, instead of keeping your threads waiting for no reason to the external operation they can do other jobs, such as answering other requests, this principle can really help server scalability.

Comment: @mkul You seem to repeatedly miss the point of async/await. It is not about multithreading or executing code in parallel. Also please note that in the specific case of ASP.NET the benefit of using async is [scalability rather than performance](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36684289/11683).