# Why Parallel.ForEach is slower than for loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postgresql, ado.net, parallel.foreach

I have a method where I used `Parallel.ForEach` to speed up processing, First it is picking small files and processing fast; for the big files, it is very slow and is slower than the `for` loop. How can I improve the speed or should I try a different approach?

Please suggest or guide me how can I improve the speed.

```
public bool CheckQueueExist()
{
    try
    {
        if (QueueVariables.NewFolderPath == "")
        {
            LoadFilePath();
        }
        string path = QueueVariables.NewFolderPath;
        DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        var files = info.GetFiles().OrderBy(p => p.CreationTime)
            .ThenBy(a => a.Name).Take(10000).ToArray();

        var batchOfFiles = files
            .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, FullName = x.FullName, Name = x.Name })
            .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 10)
            .Select(x => x.Select(v => new { v.Name, v.FullName }).ToList())
            .ToList();

        bool commitstatus = false;

        Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(
            batchOfFiles, EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering),
            new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 }, batch =>
        {
            StringBuilder strQueryBuild = new StringBuilder();
            List<string> filenamesToMove = new List<string>();

            foreach (var file in batch)
            {
                string fullfilepath = file.FullName;
                string Filename = file.Name;
                try
                {
                    string content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fullfilepath);
                    strQueryBuild.Append(content);
                    filenamesToMove.Add(fullfilepath);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    commitstatus = false;
                    AppHelper.ErrrorLog(ex, "File in USE: " + fullfilepath);
                }
            }

            int RowsAffected = 0;
            try
            {
                string connstr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
                    .ConnectionStrings["XYZ"].ConnectionString;
                using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstr))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    var tra = conn.BeginTransaction();
                    try
                    {
                        NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
                        cmd.Connection = conn;
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                        cmd.CommandText = strQueryBuild.ToString();
                        RowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        if (RowsAffected == 0)
                        {
                            RowsAffected = 1;
                        }
                        tra.Commit();
                        commitstatus = true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        AppHelper.ErrrorLog(ex, "UploadFileData-Error1");
                        RowsAffected = -1;
                        tra.Rollback();
                        commitstatus = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                commitstatus = false;
                AppHelper.ErrrorLog(ex, "ProcessQueue-Error2");
            }

            if (commitstatus)
            {
                Parallel.ForEach(filenamesToMove, filepath =>
                {
                    string Filename = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
                    MovetoSuccessFolder(filepath, Filename);
                });
            }
            else
            {
                Parallel.ForEach(filenamesToMove, filepath =>
                {
                    string Filename = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
                    MovetoFailureFolder(filepath, Filename);
                });
            }
        });

        return commitstatus;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        AppHelper.ErrrorLog(ex, "CheckQueueExist");
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: It's not. It's simply used the wrong way, to do the wrong thing . `Parallel.ForEach` is meant for data parallelism - processing a lot of in-memory data using all avalaible cores. Not for IO and *definitely* not to "speed up" slow database code

Comment: You basically DoS attack your own DB...

Comment: The question's code is causing the delays, not PForEach. You can't speed up a slow SQL query by executing more of it, you'll only increase blocking and contention for the database's limited resources  - disk, RAM, CPU and network bandwidth. *Reducing* the number of concurrent operations *increases* throughput because it reduces contention

Comment: In this case, what does the SQL query do? It looks like you're trying to import files into PostgreSQL? The fast way to do that is to use [the `COPY` command](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/copy.html). That's not shown here. There's no `BeginBinaryImport` or `BeginTextImport`.

Comment: *"it is very slow and is slower than the for loop"* -- How much slower is it? Could you provide some metrics?

Answer (score 2):

Lets se what you are actually doing here

1. Read some type of database queries from disk
2. Run these queries
3. Move files

All of these operations involve some amount of IO. Especially if the queries involve any kind of writing, since that will involve taking some kind of lock, and you risk all the queries blocking each other.

IO operations are mostly serial operations. While SSDs handle concurrent requests much better than HDDs, they still work best when reading or writing sequential data, and suffer a massive penalty when doing any kind of random operation.

Adding concurrency without understanding the actual performance problem is likely to do much more harm than good. The correct way to approach performance problems are:

1. Measure/profile - Without this you are likely to spend a bunch of time improving things that do not matter. And this needs to be done after each "improvement"
2. Improve algorithms - Algorithmic improvements often have the largest impact
3. Reduce overhead - Try to find things done repeatedly, or unnecessarily, or where there is a faster way to do the same thing. This is especially true for databases, since there are often multiple ways to do the same thing, often with drastically different performance profiles, unless you are a database expert it is easy to make mistakes that can cause terrible performance.
4. Consider parallelizing - but you need to make sure your program is actually suitable for parallelization, meaning you are compute-bound, and your algorithm is not inherently sequential in nature. And even then, consider if it worth the effort of ensuring thread safety.

Answer (score 1):

Some observations and advices:

- You have nested `Parallel.ForEach` loops: one `Parallel.ForEach` inside an other. This [is not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618338/nested-parallel-foreach-loops/75796832#75796832), because it makes difficult to control the degree of parallelism (among other reasons). `Parallel.ForEach` loops should not be nested.
- You have `Parallel.ForEach` loops with unconfigured `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`. This is not a good idea, because it results in the saturation of the `ThreadPool`. Microsoft's recommendation to leave the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` unconfigured, which is a bad advice [IMHO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538452/what-does-maxdegreeofparallelism-do/75287075#75287075), comes with a lot of exceptions and caveats. It is especially harmfull when the `Parallel.ForEach` is used to parallelize blocking I/O, like in your case.
- You are processing the files in batches of 10. Batching is a helpful technique in case the workload is granular (lightweight), to minimize the synchronization overhead. In your case the workload is blocking I/O, which is most likely chunky. The synchronization overhead is most likely negligible compared to the workload, so the batching only serves at imbalancing the parallelization. As a side node, you could use the LINQ operator [`Chunk`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.chunk) instead of the less efficient `Select`/`GroupBy`/`Select`/`ToList` approach.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several factors to `Parallel.ForEach` for being slower.

1. **Overhead of parallelization**, `Parallel.ForEach` introduces overhead for managing and coordinating parallel execution. This overhead can become significant when dealing with small or lightweight task, this leads the parallel version to be slower than the sequential one.
2. **Limited parallelism**, in the code `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` is set to 2, which limits the number of concurrent tasks to 2. Of course this will depends on your system's capabilities, this may not fully use the available resources, especially for large files.You could experiment with increasing the degree of parallelism to see if it improves performance.
3. **Shared resources**, it appears that you are using a shared `StringBuilder` (`strQueryBuild`) and lists (`filenamesToMove`) within the parallel loop. Accessing shared resources concurrently can introduce synchronisation overhead and potentially impact performance.

For improving the speed of your code you can:

1. **Optimize I/O operations**: reading file content using `System.IO.File.ReadAllText` can be a bottleneck (especially for large files). Asynchronous I/O operations can improve a lot the performances.
2. **Batch size optimisation**: you can experiment with different batch sized to find an optimal value that balances the parallelism and resource usage.Larger batch sizes can reduce the parallelization overhead, while excessively large batches may cause resource contention. Measure the performance with various batch sizes to determine the most effective value.
3. **Profiling / Performance Measurement**: using profiling tools for identify potential bottlenecks in your code.

Remember that parallelisation does not always guarantee improved performance and can introduce complexity (readability, control flow, ...)

Comment: *"Asynchronous I/O operations can improve a lot the performances."* -- Citation? As far as I know, [this is not true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683468/can-using-async-await-give-you-any-performance-benefits/36684289#36684289 "Can using async-await give you any performance benefits").

Comment: *"this may not fully use the available resources, especially for large files."* -- Could you explain why a higher `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` is more beneficial for large files than for small files? I could argue that the opposite is true, but first I would like to read your arguments.

Comment: To be honest I have a suspicion that your answer is generated by the ChatGPT, or some other AI software. Please confirm that this is not the case.