# Application(Webinterface + Cron-Jobs + HTTP-Clients) -- JAVA vs NODEJS

Tags: node.js, multithreading, cron

iam programming a prototype application with the following components:

- webinterface for admins
- doing cron jobs(statistic generation, ..)
- interact with other webservices over http

I started programming with nodejs(typescript) and i got the connection to the other services. Now i got a problem with cron-jobs in nodejs.
Iam using [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) for executing the cronjob.

Inside one job i need to obtain the status of much pc's and make a summary of it. If i would do this, this would block the main thread.
So i think I need to this in a separate thread.

How can i do this in nodejs? Should i use [webworker-threads](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworker-threads)?
Am I on the proper way?
Should i better use Java(Grails/Spring) for this?
I really like the simplicity of nodejs (for http clients, ..)

Hope someone can give me hope that iam on the proper way.

Comment: It sounds like you are concerned that the webservice calls are going to block Node's main thread... They won't, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14797359/311181.

Comment: @chardy : not entirely true. In Node.js everything runs in parallel, except your code. What this means is that all I/O code that you write in Node.js is non-blocking, while (conversely) all non-I/O code that you write in Node.js is blocking.

Comment: Well I decided to use https://github.com/rschmukler/agenda because it better fits my needs. Together with agenda i will use the clustering option of nodejs (described by @Rudy). The problem with statistic statistic generating is that it's difficult to make it non blocking. For example: if you iterate over some data with a for then it blocks.

Comment: @rudy : I agree with your statement about I/O vs non I/O. I was explicitly talking about the web service calls. When you call to a web service, you are mostly waiting on network I/O. The actual amount of code execution that blocks the thread is nominal.

Comment: @chardy I agree that webservice is an I/O operation, however it depends on what you do later on after you get your webservice result. If it takes time + no async functions at all, then you start blocking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will just use [Node Cluster](http://rowanmanning.com/posts/node-cluster-and-express/). Using cluster, a master can create a multiple workers, which means your cron wont block incoming request. Just make sure that only 1 worker doing the Cron.

I have never working with node-cron before, but I have experience with the SyncedCron. But should be the same.

For the http client there are a lot libraries doing this, you can check [Request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) or [httpclient](https://www.npmjs.com/package/httpclient).

Your code should look something like this :

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var http = require('http');
var numWorkers = require('os').cpus().length-1; // just give 1 cpu for OS to use, or maybe 2

if (cluster.isMaster) {
   console.log('Master cluster setting up ' + numWorkers + ' workers...');
   var cronPID=null; 

   for(var i = 0; i < numWorkers; i++) {
     var worker=cluster.fork();
     if(i==0){
      //instructing the first worker to assume role of SyncedCron.
      worker.send('you do it!');
      cronPID=worker.process.pid;
      console.log("worker "+cronPID+" choosed as Cron worker!");
     }
   }
   cluster.on('online', function(worker) {
       console.log('Worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' is online');
   });
   cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
       // have to revive the worker
       console.log('Worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died with code: ' + code + ', and signal: ' + signal);
       console.log('Starting a new worker');
       var newWorker=cluster.fork();
       if(cronPID==worker.process.pid)
       {   // need to re-elect a new cron worker! 
           newWorker.send('you do it!');
           cronPID=newWorker.process.pid;
           console.log("worker "+cronPID+" choosed as Cron worker!"); 
       }  
   });
}else
{  // worker sides
   process.on('message', (msg) => {
      // validate your message that you get
      // if validated, create a cron job here
   });
   // create your express below, I assume you use express instead of node's http library
   var express = require('express');
   var app = express();
   app.post...........

}
```

Note :

1. To revive the master, use something like "[forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever)"
2. Your server should have multiple core, at least 4 but I recommend more (8 maybe?).

Comment: Well I decided to use https://github.com/rschmukler/agenda because it better fits my needs. Together with agenda i will use the clustering option of nodejs (described by @Rudy). The problem with statistic statistic generating is that it's difficult to make it non blocking. For example: if you iterate over some data with a for then it blocks.