Writing/Reading to the same file when increasing pm2 replicas
I have a bull queue implemented in Redis, which accepts data in this format
{
  sessionID : '43i43ko4'
  events : [{...}]
}

This data are being sent as queue and then I process them in consumer.js. The processing part is simple

Get sessionID from payload check if it exists as file if not create
it {sessionID}.csv
Get the events from that sessionID job and append to the file

The consumer.js is running on single pm2 replica
Which is perfectly fine and its pushing the events of that sessionID in order.
But now these queues are increasing in number which i am having a hard time processing them all and memory is increasing gradually a lot, because events is sometimes very big.
So I increased the replicas of pm2 now I am scaling the consumer.js to 4 replicas.
Now i am concerned about corrupting the files because 4 jobs(Queues) with same sessionID might be excuted in the same time meaning read/write same time. Which is causing corrupting of the files
My code is
async build(job) {
        let { events, sessionId,... } = job.data;

let filename = constructSessionReplayFilePath(this.SESSION_REPLAYS_FOLDER_PATH, target, videoID);

        for(event of events){
        await compressDecompress(filename, event);
        }

compressDecompress and constructSessionReplay method
export function constructSessionReplayFilePath(path, target, videoID) {
    return path + target + '/' + videoID + '.csv';
}
export async function compressDecompress(filename, event) {
    const serializedObject = JSON.stringify(event);
    const compressedData = zlib.deflateSync(serializedObject);
    const dataLength = Buffer.alloc(4);
    dataLength.writeInt32BE(compressedData.length, 0);
    await fs.promises.appendFile(filename, dataLength);
    await fs.promises.appendFile(filename, compressedData);
}

What can i do to prevent this?
One way was to scale the application in 4 queue and one replica per queue.

want to check few info, 4 jobs(Queues) with same sessionID might be excuted in the same time are these jobs duplicate and you need only 1 of them to succeed, or you want them to be merged ?

I want them to be merged, previously when i had jobs coming they would append in order ( because they were executing in order).
Now that I increased the replicas probably it is finishing a job before the other and corrupting the file.

i dont have experience in writing files in parallel, but according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63981868/is-it-possible-to-write-to-a-file-from-two-threads-at-once-in-node-js it may not be possible. So you might need to add a little change while writing the file, you could make your pm2 processes write the file to a tmp/dir/SESSION_ID-<SOME_ID_UNIQUE_TO_PROCESS>.csv, then have another process that polls the tmp/dir and moves it to desired/dir and merge if a SESSION_ID already exist, moving files is cheap. ( This may not be elegant but might work for your use case )

What about locking the file? And the other job could wait?

i didnt know about locking, may be you could try this and see if it works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35616281/how-can-i-lock-a-file-while-writing-to-it-asynchronously

Becuase  JOB A
{
sessionID : 43034,
events: 4034
}
and if in queue JOB B adds with the same sessionID also JOB C then if i have 3 replicas these 3 will be exceuted in paralel. So if job a comes first then it locks for JOB B , job b waits but then comes job c . how to make sure now job c waits for b, because they need to be append to file in order they come. @Kuashik

as long as you use the same package to lock the file in your pm2 replicas, they'll wait correctly and only one process will be able to write at a time, So if job_a acquires lock, then job_b tries to acquire lock but has to wait for job_a to finish, now after few sec/ms job_c tries to acquire the lock but has to wait for job_a, Now lets assume job_a releases the lock, then its a race between job_b and job_c, first one to acquire lock again gets to write and other job has to wait until the lock releases,
But if order is strictly required job_a > job_b > job_c then you might need to use queue.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

This may not be the answer you are asking for, but...
Have you considered compressing the data asynchronously in a single (node) thread?
You are using zlib.deflateSync which is a synchronous function.
This means it blocks the event-loop until it finishes its task.
But you can (and I dare say "should") use its asynchronous counterpart zlib.deflate that will do the job in a separate thread.

 NOTE: NodeJS do use multiple threads for low level I/O and CPU intensive tasks: it's just the event loop which is single threaded (hence the "magic" of JS asynchronous paradigm in contrast of real concurrent programming).

This will result in better parallelization (assuming, as it seems, that your bottleneck is that compression step) not limited to 4 threads and with no concurrency issue with the write-to-file step thanks to the JS asynchrony "magic" (single threaded main event loop).
In fact you are already calling zlib.deflateSync() in an async function so you are almost already there!
The only slight complication is that zlib.deflate() uses a callback-based paradigm instead of returning a promise, but this can be solved with a simple wrapper:
const zpdeflate = async (...args) => await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    zlib.deflate(...args, function(err, data) {                             
        if (err) {                                                          
            reject(err);                                                    
        } else {                                                            
            resolve(data);                                                  
        };                                                                  
    });                                                                     
});                                                                         
                                                                            

Then you only need to replace this row:
const compressedData = zlib.deflateSync(serializedObject);                  
                                                                            

..by this other:
const compressedData = await zpdeflate(serializedObject);                   
                                                                            

And you are done!

Does this improve speed for me? @bitifet

Short answer: YES
Long answer: Try it and tell us...
But, of course: Whenever you see a function name ending in "Sync" or "_sync" it means it is a synchronous (so blocking) version of another asynchronous function.
Synchronous functions may be handy for simple scripts when we don't care much of efficiency or we need its outcome for everything else (i. e. reading a configuration file).
But, as a rule of thumb, you should avoid them because they block event-loop for no reason.
And data compression / decompression don't use to be a lightweight operation...

WARNING: I just noticed there was a (yet fixed) error in my zpdeflate() wrapper: I missed the await before new Promise(...).
Alternatively you could just remove the "async" keyword to the zpdeflate() function since it's just a wrapper over a promise. But I prefer to explicitly declare it as async not only for clarity but because, this way, if you happen to commit a typo outside the promise callback, it will normally reject instead of throwing outside.

Would this cause race condition what if 2 jobs that wants to write in the same file are next in the queue

That's the key thing: You probably won't need two jobs anymore since the heavy work is already done in separate threads by node-js and your program will be single threaded.
That's why I said that this is not the answer you were asking for... But, from my point of view it's way better.
If after doing it you still need to parallyze you can solve it messaging to specialyzed worker (so there is only one writer)... But trust me: you are far from that point and doing so would only add unnecessary overhead.

Lets continue us continue in the chat
