# What is concurrency in node.js? Explain with example?

Tags: node.js

I have been giving interviews from last few days for node.js developer. And the most commonly                   asked question in the interviews was that what is concurrency in node.js.And how we can achieve it in  node.js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How the single threaded non blocking IO model works in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795145/how-the-single-threaded-non-blocking-io-model-works-in-node-js)

Answer (score -1):

Concurrency in Node.js refers to the ability of the system to handle multiple tasks or requests simultaneously. There are different ways to achieve concurrency in Node.js like asynchronous programming, worker threads and cluster modules.

**Asynchronous programming**: Node.js uses an event-driven, non-blocking I/O model, which means that instead of waiting for an I/O operation to complete, it will start the operation and move on to the next one, while the first operation is still running and will come back to it when when its completed in order to handle the response. This allows Node.js to handle multiple operations simultaneously.

**Worker threads**: Node.js provides a built-in module called worker_threads that allows to create new threads to handle CPU-intensive tasks, which can improve the overall performance of the system.

**Cluster modules**: Cluster modules allows to create multiple worker processes that can handle incoming requests. This approach allows Node.js to take advantage of multi-core CPUs and distribute the workload across multiple processes.